# Найти повторяющиеся элементы и изменить их

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Суть задачи:

Найти повторяющиеся элементы в строке и изменить их.
А те элементы которые не повторяются тоже изменить.

Например все неповторяющиеся элементы заменить на `(`, а повторяющиеся на `)`.

Таким образом строка `seven`, должна превратиться в строку `()()(`:

```
's' => '(' // неповторяющийся
'e' => ')' // повторяющийся
'v' => '(' // неповторяющийся
'e' => ')' // повторяющийся
'n' => '(' // неповторяющийся
```

Я пытался сделать задачу через регулярные выражение - не получилось, опыта в этом нет.

Через два цикла for тоже не получилось. Не могу сделать проверку.
Буду рад помощи.

Comment: в начале пробегись по строке и в объект ключ-значение собери информацию какой элемент сколько раз встречается..... затем делай цикл от 0 до длины строки и на итерации проверяй, текущий символ сколько раз встречается в строке (за счет информации, которую ты уже собрал) - не больше 1? тогда ставь одну скобку, больше 1? - тогда другую

Comment: Спасибо за наводку. Возможно получится.

Comment: На самом деле, я бы даже добавил ваше решение по наводке Алексея в форме ответа. Ибо задача и алгоритм решения хороши. Только желательно сделать `console.log();` финального результата для наглядности (ну и может какие-то пояснения).

Comment: Хорошо, добавлю как ответ. 
P..S. Поплакал когда увидел как это задания сделали другие.. Буквально в одну строчку)

Comment: @Tom ну так рефакторингом можно заняться ;-)  почитать о модерновых функциях в JS и попробовать применить. Наверняка там какая-нибудь мапа, стрелочные функции, тернарники, все дела

Comment: Да, там много вариантов. И просто в одну строчку, и с массивами, и с мапом + some и т.д. Мой еще не самый плохой судя по решению. Учитывая что я занимаюсь этим всего недели 3, я и этому рад.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Спасибо [Алексею](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/191482/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%A8%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9) за наводку как решить задачу.
Собственно выкладываю само решение задачи

```js
function duplicateEncode(word){
 word = word.toLowerCase().split("");
 var key = {}, result = "";
 for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
  if (key[word[i]] == undefined) key[word[i]] = 1;
  else key[word[i]]++
 }
 for (var k = 0; k < word.length; k++) {
  if (key[word[k]] == 1) result += "(" ;
  else result += ")";
 }
 return result
}
```

P.S. А вот как решили задачу "большие" дяди.

```js
function duplicateEncode(word){
  return word
    .toLowerCase()
    .split('')
    .map( function (a, i, w) {
      return w.indexOf(a) == w.lastIndexOf(a) ? '(' : ')'
    })
    .join('');
}
```

Вариант с регулярным выражением

```js
function duplicateEncode(word) {
  word = word.toLowerCase();
  return word.replace(/./g, m => word.indexOf(m) == word.lastIndexOf(m) ? '(' : ')');
}
```

Comment: Я бы, на самом деле, добавил в теги "регулярные выражения", думаю, гуру регулярок обойдутся ещё более интересными решениями )))

Comment: А, вот, точно, я про lastIndexOf забыл.

Comment: Добавил для совсем гуру и любителей регулярок.

Comment: Классика )))) Правда я подразумевал чистые регулярки с заменой, но так тоже выглядит неплохо.

Comment: @Tom, отметьте как верное. Вроде выглядит достаточно полнО для ответа.

Comment: Зато у вашего решения лучше асимптотика времени работы, `O(n logn)` против `O(n^2)`